# SwiftUI: How to restrict view to only resizing in one direction?

Tags: swiftui

How can I restrict the view to resize only downwards?

I am trying to add more buttons & have the view resize to accommodate the buttons without overlapping the red rectangle above.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 55)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                    
                    VStack{
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Text("Test Button")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .frame(width: .infinity)
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding()
                        
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Text("Test Button")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .frame(width: .infinity)
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding()
                        
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Text("Test Button")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .frame(width: .infinity)
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding()
                    }
                    
                }.frame(width: 250, height: 100)
            }
            Spacer()
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `.frame(width: 250, height: 100)` to `.frame(width: 250, height: 100, alignment: .top)` Your original example defaults to `.center`, which is why it expands into the red rectangle.